# How to set wiremock to mock specified url

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock

I have microservice based app, and I need to mock one of the service.
So when Im requesting one microservice http://service1/src it triggers another one by link lets say
http://service2/src
I cannot change this link to the mocked one but I want to start wiremock somehow and fake this link, so when I will send request to http://service1/src it will trigger http://service2/src but mocked one

Im able to setup wiremock but I cannot get it directly by link http://service2/src I need to add http://localhost:8080/http://service2/src

Or maybe you can advice some another framework for such purpose

thanks for helping in advance

Comment: why not redirect all calls of http://service2/src to a localhost? I know it is not the best solutions but it can work

Comment: Can you share with us the configuration or code you use? To me it should be possible to use `http://localhost:8080/service2/src`. If that works for you.

Comment: I want to access it by just http://service2/src without localhost

Comment: yes, my solution would have worked without changing anything in jar, basically you change ip settings of machine, redirecting calls to localhost.